# Does Reflection violate LSP?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, ooad

From [Liskov Substitution Principle - www.blackwasp.co.uk](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LSP.aspx)

> One common indication of non-compliance with the LSP is when a client class checks the type of its dependencies. This may be by reading a property of an object that artificially describes its type or by using reflection to obtain the type. Often a switch statement will be used to perform a different action according to the type of the dependency. This additional complexity also violates the Open / Closed Principle (OCP), as the client class will need to be modified as further subclasses are introduced.

Does following techonolgies (that use reflection) cause a violation of LSP?

1. Dependency Injection
2. Inversion Of Control

Note: I am from C# background.

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2008/06/30/dependency-injection-is-dead.aspx

> Reflection; most (perhaps all?) Dependency Injection containers rely on some extent on Reflection – dynamically inspecting objects and determining their dependencies.

REFERENCES:

1. [Hierarchy violates Liskov - so what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938071/hierarchy-violates-liskov-so-what)
2. [How can I avoid breaking Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778354/how-can-i-avoid-breaking-liskov-substitution-principle-lsp)
3. [Does Liskov Substitution Principle also apply to classes implementing an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921465/does-liskov-substitution-principle-also-apply-to-classes-implementing-an-interfa)
4. [Does this violate the Liskov substitution principle, and if so, what do I do about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996819/does-this-violate-the-liskov-substitution-principle-and-if-so-what-do-i-do-abo)
5. [Does GWT's ActivityMapper violate the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368684/does-gwts-activitymapper-violate-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Comment: *"One common indication of non-compliance with the LSP is ... reflection"* - this does not mean that *all uses* of reflection violate LSP.

Answer (score 3):

The way i understand LSP, it simply states that subclasses should be substitutable for their base class in every situation, that is whenever you pass an instance of the base class *(to a method, constructor, service, etc ..)* you should be able to pass an instance of the subclass instead without any code modification for this to work. Like any other principle, LSP is a guideline and not a strict rule, it makes our code more open for extensibility. When framework writers use reflection they are not breaking LSP, you can simply contrast this with frameworks using [Service Location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) which is now considered an anti-pattern by many OO proponents but they have to do that so their framework let you choose your own container. as always, it is a tradeoff and it depends on the **Context** *(**your** own specific use case)*.